# Docker Bitbucket start stop at: c.a.s.i.hazelcast.HazelcastLifecycle Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, bitbucket

Im trying to start a bitbucketserver. Im behind a proxy and I set the proxy configuration.

Every time I try to start the container, spring stop here:

```
c.a.s.i.hazelcast.HazelcastLifecycle Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities
```

Have I to configure the proxy in Hazelcast too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your properties in `/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/bitbucket.properties`
You need these properties to work behind a proxy:

```
hazelcast.network.multicast=true
hazelcast.group.name=[put a unique name in here]
hazelcast.group.password=[put in a group password here]
server.proxy-name=[url of your bit bucket instance]
server.proxy-port=443
server.redirect-port=443
server.secure=true
server.scheme=https
```

Refer to the official documentation here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/install-bitbucket-data-center-872139817.html